# What would the activation record look like for the following code?

Tags: c

```
int test (int integer ){
    int results =0 ;
    results = 10 - integer;
    printf("%d \n", &integer);
    return results;
}


void main(){
    printf("%d \n", test(1));

}
```

Comment: It would look like me beating you repeatedly for using `void main()`.

Comment: @Chris, maybe the OP is a disciple of Herbert Schildt.

Comment: Activation record == stack frame.  This question == homework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activation records / stack frames are dependent on both the architecture and the platform.  That said, a vaguely generic one would look like

```
+----------------+
| integer        |
+----------------+
| return address |
+-----------------
| link pointer   |
| (aka saved     |
| base pointer   |
+----------------+
| results        |
+----------------+
```

There could be other things in there as well such as saved registers but this should give you a rough idea.

Answer (score 0):

Google will lead you to Wikipedia, which in turn will give you the background needed to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Consult the [Dragon Book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Book_%28computer_science%29).